# How do I add printers from a windows print server

Tags: printing

I am installing Ubuntu 12.10 in a Windows environment. Currently, all of our printers are served. For instance, our main printer is on \SST-DC5\COPIER. I am trying to figure out how to add these printers to Ubuntu. I don't want to create a print server, and I don't want to allow windows users to print to me. That seems to be 99% of the answers I am finding. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to connect to a printer on a Windows print server. To do this, you want to connect to your printer using a technology known as [Samba](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba).

Start the Printers application, and click the Add Printer button. In the window that appears, click the Network Printer tree and then the Windows Printer via SAMBA item. 
In the entry box, type the name of the print server, a `/`, then the name of your printer, for example, SST-DC5/COPIER.

[image: Adding a windows printer]

Then follow the instructions as if you were adding a regular printer.